# ggplot2 - annotate text with superscript

Tags: r, ggplot2, subscript

I want to add an R^2 value to my plot.  I passed the label to geom_text() as follows;

```
 geom_text(aes(x,y,label=caption),parse=T,
        data.frame(x=-2,y=80,caption=("R^2=0.43"))))
```

but it plots as =(R^2,0.43).  Any ideas?

Comment: How do I add a separate line after the R^2=0.43, e.g. p=0.763?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want your caption to be "R^2==0.43".  Look at the help page for `plotmath`.  There it shows that `==` gives you equals.

EDIT:

To answer the comment after the question, you can use atop in the expression. `"atop(R^2==0.43,p==0.763)"`  This works for two lines, but not more.

Comment: Great,thanks!  Just getting familiar with plotmath.  Sorry if the question seemed stupid